# Windows formated disks; are they any use on Ubuntu?

Tags: disk, window, format

I have a bunch of disks (digital dictionaries, encyclopedia) on Windows format.  Is it possible to read them with Ubuntu?(12:10) When I just put them in my drive, window says "no respinse" and it darkens out (sometimes freeze)

Comment: Impossible to answer... You might be able to extract the files from the disc. Using them depends on what kind of files they are.You need to search for the files on google. WINE might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

i have some cds with windows files too and for me it always worked using WINE. try to look for the right .exe file and open it with WINE.

Comment: thanx for answer.  I will get back to you with file format info.  I do have WINE installed already and I naively expected it would work its way toward Windows format disks or at least direct me to a certain avenue, but disappointingly just "not responding".  Does not WINE work automatically?  Or is there a way to manuever?

Answer (score 1):

You can also install vmware player or virtualbox and install wondow (need a valid product key) for the full wondow experience within linux.
You can then operate the cds natively.

Comment: thanks for answer.  this vmplayer and virtualbox are both software that is capable of reading Windows formated files?   I am a recent defect from Windows and have no plan to go back there

Comment: thanks for answer.  this vmplayer and virtualbox are both software that is capable of reading Windows formated files?  I am a recent defect from Windows and have no plan to go back there. Id like to stick to Linux. Is conversion btween these two a very complicated affair?

Comment: These pieces of software allow wondow tonbe run in a virtual machine. So it is having wondow inside linux to help with the pain of migrating but staying productive.